# Be $f:\mathbb{R}^{2}\to \mathbb{R}^{2}$ a continuous function and $g(x)=\int_0^1 \! f(x,y) \, \mathrm{d}y.$ Proves that g is continuous.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I don't see how to solve the following problem, I think that it's like a generalization of the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Be  $f:\mathbb{R}^{2}\to \mathbb{R}^{2}$ a continuous function and $g(x)=\int_0^1 \! f(x,y) \, \mathrm{d}y.$ Proves that g is continuous.

Would someone please help me on this question? Thank you very much.

Comment: Actually this result doesn't have much to do with the FTC.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $f(x,y)$ is uniformly continuous on any $[a,b]\times [0,1].$